# Keras model fit ValueError expected input_1 to be one number larger than the size of my array

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to create an Autoencoder neural network for finding outliers using Keras TensorFlow, my data is a list of texts with one word per line, it is the following: https://pastebin.com/hEvm6qWg it has 139 lines.

When I fit my model with my data, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (139,) but got array with shape (140,)
```

But I can't tell why it recognizes it as 140 shape array, my entire code is as follows:

```py
from keras import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

with open('drawables.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
    dados = arquivo.read().splitlines()

tokenizer = Tokenizer(filters='')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(dados)

x_dados = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(dados, mode="freq")

tamanho = len(tokenizer.word_index)

x = Input(shape=(tamanho,))

# Encoder
hidden_1 = Dense(tamanho, activation='relu')(x)
h = Dense(tamanho, activation='relu')(hidden_1)

# Decoder
hidden_2 = Dense(tamanho, activation='relu')(h)
r = Dense(tamanho, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_2)

autoencoder = Model(input=x, output=r)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

autoencoder.fit(x_dados, epochs=5, shuffle=False)
```

I am utterly lost, I can't even tell if my approach to an autoencoder network is the correct one, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word_index` in `Tokenizer` start from 1 not from zero

Example:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(filters='')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(["this a cat", "this is a dog"])
print (tokenizer.word_index)
```

Output:

```
{'this': 1, 'a': 2, 'cat': 3, 'is': 4, 'dog': 5}
```

Index is starting from 1 not from zero. So when we create `term frequency` matrix using these indices

```
x_dados = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(["this a cat", "this is a dog"], mode="freq")
```

The shape of `x_dados` will be `2x6` because numpy arrays are indexed from 0.

so no:of columns in `x_dados = 1+len(tokenizer.word_index)`

So to fix your code change

```
tamanho = len(tokenizer.word_index)
```

to

```
tamanho = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
```

### Working sample:

```
dados = ["this is a  cat", "that is a dog and a cat"]*100
tokenizer = Tokenizer(filters='')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(dados)

x_dados = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(dados, mode="freq")
tamanho = len(tokenizer.word_index)+1
x = Input(shape=(tamanho,))

# Encoder
hidden_1 = Dense(tamanho, activation='relu')(x)
h = Dense(tamanho, activation='relu')(hidden_1)

# Decoder
hidden_2 = Dense(tamanho, activation='relu')(h)
r = Dense(tamanho, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_2)

autoencoder = Model(input=x, output=r)
print (autoencoder.summary())

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
autoencoder.fit(x_dados, x_dados, epochs=5, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've made the code changes you mentioned, now I'm getting a IndexError: list index out of range error, but I'm lost on what the cause can be.

Comment: The line of the fit method:
autoencoder.fit(x_dados, epochs=5, shuffle=False)

Comment: Should not it be `autoencoder.fit(x_dados,x_dados, epochs=5, shuffle=False)` you are missing your y's (which is same as x in autoencoder)

Comment: How could I miss that?? it somehow worked! now I just need to plot it and see if the data made sense, but it ran! Thanks! 